# Website CSS not loading - The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, web-development-server

I am trying to fix a website and I am new to this. The website was working just fine a couple of days back but now not able to load the CSS or image files. A user in IAM created a new access key id 4 days ago so I believe the issue might have arisen that time but I am not sure.

website link: www.sgmoid.com

On the browser, I clicked on view source code and then tried clicking a link to which I could see the following screenshot

[Access Key Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY44k.png)

sample error Url: https://sgmoid-static-new.s3.amazonaws.com/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVV5DRP7QE7M7XI6C&Signature=tfA%2F%2BAzv3EKYetw20ahfn%2FdvvzM%3D&Expires=1579260660

However, if I manually remove the later part on the browser after .css or .png then the URL is working fine.

I also checked in S3, the bucket is having a public access

I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: If this access key is necessary for your application have you tried switching it out for one that provides access to your resource?

Comment: Do you have access to the site html? Does the site html have signed urls embedded in the source itself?

Comment: the access was hardcoded into the code and changing and re-deploying the code fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some process or application has embedded a signed URL into the internal site source, which includes an access key ID in the url.

The error message "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" indicates that there's an issue with the credentials that you're using. The access key that you're using might have been deleted, or the associated AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role or user might have been deleted.

The S3 bucket fully public. There's no need to have signed urls here.

Someone deleted or inactivated the access key.

It needs to be activated again, or your website needs to be updated with a new access key.